# pycharm не видит папки .idea

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

Собственно вопрос в топике. В windows папка есть, в браузере pycharm нету. В настройках из неотображаемых папок всё удалил. Просто начал работать с гитом и загрузилась туда эта папка мне вовсе ненужная.

Comment: какой режим выбран в браузере pycharm? Там несколько разных

Comment: @Эникейщик как это посмотреть?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-tool-window.html#views должно быть Project, тогда показывает именно папки и файлы

Comment: @Эникейщик все равно не видит https://prnt.sc/Q1awlrfqbjbd

Comment: а если Project, а не Project Files? У меня только что в Project Files было не видно, а в Project видно. А когда папку открыл, то и в Project Files стало видно.

Comment: @Эникейщик да, пощелкал и стало видно, спасибо